# anguarl1 ng-repeat on items returned async in parents ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

I am endeavoring to have an `<ng-repeat>` on items that are returned in a parent elements' `ng-init`. I feel like the async nature of the `ng-init` intitialization of this array is causing the `ng-repeat` to not render. Here is my HTML/angular setup

```
<span ng-click=\"showArtist(song.artist.key)\" class=\"song_alias\" 
ng-init=\"collabSongs = getSongsFromCollab(song.collaboration_id); \" >
   {{song.artist.alias}}
   <span ng-repeat=\"songItem in collabSongs\" 
     ng-init=\"songCollabItem = songForKey(songItem); index = $index\">
      {{index != (collabSongs.length - 1) ? songCollabItem.artist.alias : 'goo'}}
   </span>
</span>
```

however even though i am logging out that `getSongsFromCollab()` is properly returning an array of non zero elements (2) albeit asynchronously, i don't seen the inner `<span>` ever rendered in the dom and instead just see:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: songItem in collabSongs -->
```

for reference here is the firebase calling function which populates collabSongs in the parent's `ng-init`

```
    $scope.getSongsFromCollab = function(collaboration) {
  console.log('getSongs' , collaboration);
  var songsRef =  new Firebase(FBURL + 'collaboration_songs').child(collaboration).child('songs');
  songsRef.once("value", function(data){
      var val = data.val();
      var array_of_songs = [];
      var keys = Object.keys(val);
      for (var i= 0; i<keys.length; i++){
        array_of_songs.push(val[keys[i]]);
      }
      console.log(array_of_songs);
      return array_of_songs;
  });

};
```

Notice that i am logging out the array so i have confirmed it has the desired data in the case when i get the above behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collabSongs` is set to the return value of `getSongsFromCollab`, which is not the return value of the callback function to `songsRef.once`. You are trying to synchronously set a value returned from an async function. $firebaseArray synchronously returns an array that is later populated with the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think i can just do the following

```
   $scope.getSongsFromCollab = function(collaboration) {
    var songsRef =  new Firebase(FBURL + 'collaboration_songs').child(collaboration).child('songs');
    return $firebaseArray(songsRef);
};
```

angularfire does magic for binding async objects return from firebased with angular. any explanation i would love to hear !

Comment: If you inspect the return value of $firebaseArray you will see that it is initially an empty array.